# Getting access to html element in a twitter iframe, without src property

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been using Python with BeautifulSoup 4 to scrape the data out of unglobal website. Some companies over there, like this one: https://www.unglobalcompact.org/what-is-gc/participants/2968-Orsted-A-S
have twitter accounts. I would like to access the names of the twitter accounts. Problem is that it is inside of an iframe without a src property. I know that iframe is called by a different request than the rest of the website, but I wonder now if it is even possible to acess it without src property visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `selenium` to do this. Here is the full code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = "https://www.unglobalcompact.org/what-is-gc/participants/2968-Orsted-A-S "

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get(url)

iframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="twitter-widget-0"]')))

driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

names = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="TweetAuthor-name Identity-name customisable-highlight"]')

names = [name.text for name in names]
 
try:
    name = max(set(names), key=names.count)  #Finds the most frequently occurring name. This is because the same author has also retweeted tweets made by others. These retweets would contain the name of other people. The most frequently occurring name is the name of the author.
    print(name)

except ValueError:
    print("No Twitter Feed Found!")

driver.close()
```

Output:

```
Ørsted
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have another question tho :x How to check if WebElement is empty? I know how to check if it exists, but that is pretty simple.

Comment: And coming to your question, what do you mean by empty?

Comment: In case of some companies, the body element exists, but it is empty(no divs inside). I need to add some kind of an if statement so the code will run only if the body element is not empty.

Comment: Okay...Shall I provide you the solution for that by 2:30 pm GMT? Cuz I have online classes now.

Comment: Ok ok. Thanks :D

Comment: Could you provide the link of one such company (where the body element is empty) ? So that it would be easier for testing.

Comment: https://www.unglobalcompact.org//what-is-gc/participants/33931

Comment: Found an easier solution i think. I do not need banned accounts scraped anyway, so I just check for length of find_elements_by_xpath( "html/body/div") and if it is 0 then it means that account is banned, cause there is nothing in body tag.

Comment: Yeah...That is another way of doing it.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the help <3 It is my first post here, as I could find all the solutions of a all the problems that I had before online :p